# CSS word-break combined with text-overflow

Tags: css

So I am trying to combine `word-break` with `text-overflow` which does work at some point but not how it should be.

For example, I have set up this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/43Ske/)

CSS:

```
width: 200px;
padding: 8px;
border:1px solid blue;
word-break: break-word;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
```

For clarification, once text is broken in to parts it should fill box and at the end of the text there should be 3 dots.
Currently there is just a single line where it works.

Comment: FWIW: There is a [proposal and discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jan/0627.html) in www-style@w3.org mailing-list as for using text-overflow for multiline texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible using CSS.

The only thing you could do is specify the `height`, and `overflow:hidden`. (No ellipsis in the end.)

This is stated in the [W3 spec for text-overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-text-20021024/#text-overflow-ellipsis).

> **ellipsis**
>   an ellipsis string is inserted at each box boundaries where a
>   text overflow occurs. The values of these ellipsis strings is
>   determined by the 'text-overflow-ellipsis' property. The insertions
>   take place at the boundary of the last full glyph representation of a
>   line of text
>   ... 
>   In other words, the text-overflow-mode only affects the textual content of a block element 
>   which participate in its own inline flow.

You will need to use JavaScript for achieving this.

Here is an example of a jQuery plugin : http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/