# How to truncate a text in a html

Tags: html, css

I want to truncate a text in a html page.

style.css:

```
p {
 height: 30%;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

index.html

```
<p>
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
</p>
```

I want to get a result such:

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh...
```

But I can't got this result using the style.css mentioned below.How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058004/applying-an-ellipsis-to-multiline-text)

Answer (score 4):

you maybe looking for this

```css
p{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height:56px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
```

Note: its only works on webkit browsers

Comment: it's not browser compatible. it works only in `webkit`

Comment: yep was adding this on ans itself

Answer (score 3):

The CSS-Rule `word-wrap: break-word;` will force even long words like yours to break at the end of the div. You can also limit the width of the div to have a similar effect as you postet.

```css
p {
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>
 hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
</p>
```

Comment: if you use `word-wrap` the `ellipsis` won't apply here.

Comment: @SuperUser yes thats true. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: I want to display the `...` when the the text was overflowed

Comment: no i don't have any solution, but OP wants both thing, `ellipsis` with `word-wrap`...

Comment: @paraclub101 a quick internet search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895028/css-word-break-combined-with-text-overflow

Comment: @paraclub101 if you want only webkit fixes then you can take reference from
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iBtep

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it is normally used when it is expected that long words will be introduced that will break your layout.

```
p { overflow-wrap: break-word }
```

This will cause that lines will break between any two characters. You can also use:

```
word-break: break-all
```

... if you expect Chinese, Japanese, and Korean to be inserted in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap:

```
<!-- Block level -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-truncate">
    Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Inline level -->
  <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width:150px;">
    Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex> communi.
</span>
```

Will give you:

Praeterea iter e...

Praeterea iter est q...

More at:
[Bootstrap Text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)